# Build "ImageTargets" shared library-Vuforia sample application

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, sample, vuforia

I followed the procedure according to the site: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-3-compiling-running-vuforia-sample-app.

I tried to build ImageTargets shared library through cygwin but the displayed message is:

```
$ ndk-build
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
/cygdrive/c/Users/Dimitris/Desktop/ANDROID/adt-bundle-windows-x86/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-local.mk:130: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

I can assure you that no empty character is to the path of my project directory.

I have located ImageTargets project into the folder : `C:\Users\Dimitris\Desktop\ANDROID\adt-bundle-windows-x86\samples`

So i ran the commands:

`$ cd C:/Users/Dimitris/Desktop/ANDROID/adt-bundle-windows-x86/samples`

and

`$ ndk-build`

Comment: What is the value of your `NDK_PROJECT_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: The problem has solved!!I found the path.During the installation of Vuforia a new folder had been created in C:\Development...... bla bla bla...thank you very much Al G...

Comment: In fact I reinstalled everything according to Vuforia site and for the time being everything works great....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has solved!!I found the path.During the installation of Vuforia a new folder had been created in C:\Development...... bla bla bla...
In fact I reinstalled everything according to Vuforia site and for the time being everything works great... thank you very much Al G...